# Where does django read request language code and sneak it into DecimalField output?

Tags: django

I'm a little confused why my site is occasionally rendering commas as decimal separators.

I've disabled `USE_L10N` now which should take care of the issue, but I'm still curious where this per request language code to DecimalField magic is happening. There are no instances of `localize=True` anywhere in my codebase.

My only thought is that the browser requests a language code other than `en-us` and django automatically responds by converting decimal fields, but I can't seem to find where this happens in the `django 1.4` source.

Example here: click through products and watch price deicmal separator.
http://www.grovemade.com/product/iphone-5-case/#amongshadows-bamboo-iphone-5-case

The output is cached per URL w/o regard to language code which is why you're seeing some prices with decimal separators as `,` vs `.`. The ones with `0,00` must have been cached from a non `en-us` accept request.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as to where this is happening, its in [the template system](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/template/base.py#L850):

```
def _render_value_in_context(value, context):
    """
    Converts any value to a string to become part of a rendered template. This
    means escaping, if required, and conversion to a unicode object. If value
    is a string, it is expected to have already been translated.
    """
    value = localtime(value, use_tz=context.use_tz)
    value = localize(value, use_l10n=context.use_l10n)
    value = force_unicode(value)
    if ((context.autoescape and not isinstance(value, SafeData)) or
            isinstance(value, EscapeData)):
        return escape(value)
    else:
        return value
```

[`localize`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/formats.py#L152) from `django.utils.formats`:

```
def localize(value, use_l10n=None):
    """
    Checks if value is a localizable type (date, number...) and returns it
    formatted as a string using current locale format.

    If use_l10n is provided and is not None, that will force the value to
    be localized (or not), overriding the value of settings.USE_L10N.
    """
    if isinstance(value, bool):
        return mark_safe(six.text_type(value))
    elif isinstance(value, (decimal.Decimal, float) + six.integer_types):
        return number_format(value, use_l10n=use_l10n)
    elif isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
        return date_format(value, 'DATETIME_FORMAT', use_l10n=use_l10n)
    elif isinstance(value, datetime.date):
        return date_format(value, use_l10n=use_l10n)
    elif isinstance(value, datetime.time):
        return time_format(value, 'TIME_FORMAT', use_l10n=use_l10n)
    else:
        return value
```

I think what's happening is that your [template is setting localize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/formatting/#template-tags) somewhere to true, which is overriding your settings `USE_L10N` setting.

Or you may have some stale settings files that are still in use. Try clearing out `.pyc` and your cache and try again.

Comment: Thank you for being the first person who understands the question! This explains it perfectly; even though I don't use localize=True in my field definition, it seems every localizable value is automatically sent through the localize function, using a global settings flag. I was misled by the docs which say to give a `localize=True` argument to  a field.